# try to change navigationbar background color but failed

Tags: ios, iphone

I used the code below to change the background color of navigationbar

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithHexString:@"6cd3c5"]];

    [super viewDidLoad];

}
```

the bar background color does not change immediately, I have to `pushViewController:someViewController`

and go back, the color can change.

Your comment welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`appearance` is used for the future appearance. if you want to appearance then use before the view load.

else use

```
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithHexString:@"6cd3c5"]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithHexString:@"6cd3c5"]];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO];
```

[Read this](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-navigation-status-bar-ios-7/) for more clarification.